# How to insert an array into another array at a given index?

Tags: python, list

```
def insert(listA, listB, index):
    for item in listA:
         listB.append(item)

    print(listB)
```

This outputs

```
>>> insert([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)

>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

How do I make it output: `[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3]`

Comment: `listA[:index] + listB + listA[index:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listA[index:index] = listB

This will insert your list B to list A, stating at index.

example:

a = [1,2,3]

b = [4,5,6]

a[2:2] = b

a is now [1,2,4,5,6,3]

Answer (score 0):

One way could be by constructing a new list by slicing `listA` according to `index`:

```
def insert(listA, listB, index):
    return listA[0:index] + listB + listA[index:]
```

(Note that this implementation excludes any parameter validations, for bravity's sake)